# How to copy content from a text file to another text file in C

Tags: c, function, text, struct, randomaccessfile

I am trying to copy the content of the text file "data" to a text file called "raf". Below is the content of the "data" file:

```
30     Clinton,Bill      300.30
50     Carter,Jimmy      500.50
60     Bush,George       60.60
20     Reagan,Ronald     200.20
10     Nixon,Kathy       100.10
40     Bush,Barba        400.40
90     Obama,Barack      900.90
```

---

**My goal is to get an output that looks like this**:

```
ID       NAME            BALANCE
---------------------------------------
10       Nixon,Kathy     100.10
20       Reagan,Ronald   200.20
30       Clinton,Bill    300.30
40       Bush,Barba      400.40
50       Carter,Jimmy    500.50
60       Bush,George     60.60
0        bbbb             0.00
0        bbbb             0.00
90     Obama,Barack      900.90
0        bbbb             0.00
```

---

**However this is what I am actually getting**:

```
ID       NAME            BALANCE
---------------------------------------
10       Nixon,Kathy     100.10
20       Reagan,Ronald   200.20
30       Clinton,Bill    300.30
40       Bush,Barba      400.40
50       Carter,Jimmy    500.50
60       Bush,George     60.60
60       Bush,George     60.60
60       Bush,George     60.60
60       Bush,George     60.60
60       Bush,George     60.60


Press any key to continue . . .
```

---

Here is my code currently:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>



struct PERSON
{
int ID;
char name[20];
float balance;

};


void DisplayText(char FullText[]);
void RAF(char *fname);
void DisplayRAF(char *fname);
void CopyText2RAF(char* txtname, char* rafname);


int main()
{
char FullText[500];

printf("Display text file\n\n");
DisplayText(FullText);
RAF("raf.txt");

//printf("\n\n");
//printf("Display after Initializing Randon Access File\n\n");
//DisplayRAF("raf.txt");

 printf("\n\nDisplay after Copying text to Random Access File");
 CopyText2RAF("data.txt","raf.txt");
 printf("\n\n");

 DisplayRAF("raf.txt");




 printf("\n\n");
 system("PAUSE");
 return 0;

 }

void DisplayText(char FullText[])
{
FILE * fp;
fp = fopen("data.txt","r");
int i;

printf("ID \t NAME \t\t BALANCE \n");
printf("---------------------------------------\n");
for(i=0;i<7; i++)
{
    fgets(FullText,500,fp);
    printf("%s", FullText);
}

printf("\n");

free(FullText);
fclose(fp);
}

void RAF(char *fname)
{
FILE * f;
struct PERSON p = {0 , "bbbb", 0.0};

// OPEN THE RAF FILE
f = fopen(fname,"wb");

//INITIALIZE THE FILE WITH RECORD p
int i;
for(i=1; i<=10; i++)
{
   fwrite((char *)&p,sizeof(p),1,f);
}

fclose(f);
}

void DisplayRAF(char *fname)
{
FILE * f = fopen(fname,"rb");
struct PERSON p;

int i;
printf("ID \t NAME \t\t BALANCE \n");
printf("---------------------------------------\n");

for(i=1; i<=10; i++)
{
    fread((char *)&p, sizeof(p),1,f);
    printf("%d \t %s \t %.2f \n",p.ID, p.name, p.balance);
}

fclose(f);
}

void CopyText2RAF(char* txtname, char* rafname)
{
FILE * ftxt = fopen(txtname,"r");
FILE * fraf = fopen(rafname,"wb");



//READ FROM TEXT FILE
struct PERSON p;
fscanf(ftxt, "%d %s %f", &p.ID, p.name, &p.balance);

while(! feof(ftxt))
{
    int ByteOfText = ((p.ID/10-1)*sizeof(p));
    fseek(fraf,ByteOfText, SEEK_SET);
    fwrite((char *)&p, sizeof(p), 1, fraf);
    fscanf(ftxt, "%d %s %f", &p.ID, p.name, &p.balance);
}

fclose(ftxt);
fclose(fraf);
}
```

---

For some reason after I copy the text file to the RAF file the display only reads up until ID 60 and then it repeats till the for loop is complete. I don't get why the  content that P was initialized to doesn't get printed out for ID 70 and 80. ID 90 is not printed at all. Instead its the info for ID 60.Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that when you open the file to update it in the `CopyText2RAF` function you use:

```
FILE * fraf = fopen(rafname,"wb");
```

This opens an empty file for writing and destroys any prior existing content. That is why you do not have any of the previously written data there.

Instead you want to use

```
FILE * fraf = fopen(rafname,"r+b");
```

The `r+` indicates you want the file open for both reading and writing (and the file must already exist).

Making this change to your program and running it I got the result:

Display after Copying text to Random Access File

```
ID   NAME        BALANCE 
---------------------------------------
10   Nixon,Kathy     100.10 
20   Reagan,Ronald   200.20 
30   Clinton,Bill    300.30 
40   Bush,Barba      400.40 
50   Carter,Jimmy    500.50 
60   Bush,George     60.60 
0    bbbb    0.00 
0    bbbb    0.00 
0    bbbb    0.00 
0    bbbb    0.00
```

However you'll notice that last one is missing. That is because you read the value from the text file at the end of your loop and then loop back and it checks if its at the end of the file before continuing. So it never writes the last one.
I modified that function to the following:

```
void CopyText2RAF(char* txtname, char* rafname)
{
    FILE * ftxt = fopen(txtname,"r");
    FILE * fraf = fopen(rafname,"r+b");

    //READ FROM TEXT FILE
    struct PERSON p;

    while(! feof(ftxt))
    {
        int ByteOfText;
        fscanf(ftxt, "%d %s %f", &p.ID, p.name, &p.balance);
        ByteOfText = ((p.ID/10-1)*sizeof(p));
        fseek(fraf,ByteOfText, SEEK_SET);
        fwrite((char *)&p, sizeof(p), 1, fraf);
    }

    fclose(ftxt);
    fclose(fraf);
}
```

Now it produces the result:

Display after Copying text to Random Access File

```
ID   NAME        BALANCE 
---------------------------------------
10   Nixon,Kathy     100.10 
20   Reagan,Ronald   200.20 
30   Clinton,Bill    300.30 
40   Bush,Barba      400.40 
50   Carter,Jimmy    500.50 
60   Bush,George     60.60 
0    bbbb    0.00 
0    bbbb    0.00 
90   Obama,Barack    900.90 
0    bbbb    0.00
```